# Difference between rows of the same column if particular conditions are met

Tags: sql, sybase

Im trying to create a new column called `Diff` that contains the difference between different rows of the same Column called `Rep`, which is an Integer.

My table looks as follows:

```
------------------------
security_ID | Date | Rep 
------------------------
2256        |202001|  0
2257        |202002|  1
2258        |202003|  2
2256        |202002|  3
2256        |202003|  5
```

For a particular `security_ID` I want to get the difference in `Rep` if the `Date`'s, which are Integer, are different by 1 (for eg. with 202002-202001 = 1). For example, I want the output to be:

```
-------------------------------
security_ID | Date | Rep | Diff
-------------------------------
2256        |202001|  0  |  0
2257        |202002|  1  |  1 
2258        |202003|  2  |  2 
2256        |202002|  3  |  3 
2256        |202003|  5  |  2
```

With the last row being a `Diff` of 2, because the calculation would be 5-3 (for the `Date` 202003 and 202002, respectively) for the `security_ID` 2256.

**Edit**: Because Sybase doesn't have `LAG()` I tried the following:

```
SELECT security_ID, Date, Rep, 
MIN(Rep) OVER (PARTITION BY Date, security_ID rows between current row and 1 following) - Rep as "Diff"
from
my_table
```

But this does not give me the right answer. For example, with the last and penultimate row difference above `Diff` is 0 according to the above.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you storing dates as integers?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I'm using existing tables, not created by me

Comment: Does Sybase support window function at all ?

Comment: Is `date` column data type is `date` or character ? Will it be always in increasing order from lower to higher for a particular `security_id` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 `date` is actually an integer (I didn't make this table). And it is in increasing order from lower to higher for a particular `security_id`

Comment: Could you check the answer now and validate if the logic works for you ? Would be my last try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `date` column is always in increasing order we can use `left join` with self and bring the previous `rep` value and then calculate the difference outside. As,

```
select security_id,dt,rep,(rep-prev_rep) diff
  from
(
select t1.security_id,t1.dt,t1.rep,
       coalesce(t2.rep,0) prev_rep
  from mytable t1
  left join mytable t2
    on t1.security_id = t2.security_id
   and t2.dt = t1.dt - 1
)
order by rep;
```

***Edit: addressing the query attempt by OP***

If you can use window function as you have shown , you can modify the query as below,

```
select security_id
     , dt
     , rep
     , (rep-coalesce(max(rep) over (partition by security_id order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0)) diff
from mytable;
order by rep
```

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't a LAG() function in Sybase

Comment: Oops got it..would delete it.:(

Comment: The first query works. I haven't tried the second one yet

Comment: Great!!! Hope the second one should work as per the expectation.